# Maximum value of a modulus function

Tags: functions, contest-math, absolute-value

> Let $0 \leq a \leq x \leq 100$ and $f(x) = |x-a|+|x-100|+|x-a-50|$,
> then the maximum value of $f(x)$ becomes $100$ when $a$ is equal to
> what?

As $a \leq x$, so $|x-a| = x-a$ and as $x \leq 100$, so $|x-100| = 100 -x$.

Now $f(x) = 100-a + |x-a-50|$

As per the question;
$f(x) = 100-a + |x-a-50| = 100$
$\Rightarrow |x-a-50| = a $

How can we proceed from here to find the value of $a$ when $f(x)$ will be maximum i.e. $100$ ? Please help !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=[a,100]$.

Let us start from your expression :

$$f(x) = 100-a + |x-a-50| $$

$f$ takes its maximum $f(x_{max})=100$ if and only if
$$g(x) := |x-(a+50)| - a $$

takes its maximum $g(x_{max})=0$.

The important point is that **there are two "ways" a function can take its maximum :**

- (1) on an interior point of $I=[a,100]$ (the domain of definition of $g$).
- (2) or on a border point, i.e., at one of the bounds $a$ or $100$ of $I$.

As function $g$ cannot have a maximum in the interior of  $I=[a,100]$ (see explanation $\star$ below), we are in the case (2).

The issue becomes then :

$$\max(g(a),g(100))=0$$

Otherwise said, $a$ must be such that :

$$\max(50-a,|50-a|-a)=0\tag{1}$$

In fact, (1) can be reduced to :

$$50-a=0 \tag{2}$$

as proved by the following graphics where (red) curve $y=50-a$ is always above (blue) curve $y=|50-a|-a$

[image]

As a consequence, the only possible value : $a=50$.

Explanation of $\star$:

- if $a+50 \le 100 \iff a \le 50$, function $g$
  is decreasing, then increasing (a "V" shape) : it has a minimum in $x=a+50$ but no maximum.
- otherwise, if $a > 50$, function $g$ is always decreasing on interval $I=[a,100]$.

**Edit** : In fact, there is a slightly more sophisticated version for the latter explanation using "**maximum modulus property**" : $g$ being a **convex** function, whatever the  compact domain of definition $[a,b]$ to which $g$ is restricted, its maximum is attained in one of the bounds $a$ or $b$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121819/305862)).

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer! However the solution mentioned for this problem states that it has a single answer i.e 50.

Please see the solution here : https://tinyurl.com/259ca743

Comment: Indeed, I have realized what I had missed (I haven't yet had a look at the solution). I am going to give a corrected version.

Comment: I don't understand the solution you mention.